# Verificar a compatibilidade da minha aplicação com os browsers

Tags: navegador-de-internet, aplicação-web

De um modo geral, como eu posso verificar a compatibilidade da minha aplicação web com os navegadores mais usados (e suas versões) para que não ocorra problema com as funcionalidades?

Comment: Eu utilizo o browserstack.com, ele emula diversos navegadores, é muito bacana.

Comment: Eu também costumava utilizar, mas quando eu uso o `localhost` eu tenho problemas pra testar, na verdade, nunca consegui testar utilizando o `localhost`.

Comment: No localhost não vai mesmo, porem, se você configurar no firewall as portas, roteador e tal, você pode acessar seu IP, ai daria certo utilizar essa ferramenta com seu localhost.

Comment: Disso eu não sabia! Valeu mesmo!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única forma de **garantir** a compatibilidade é testando a aplicação em todas as versões que você suporta.

Onde trabalho, na Atlassian, isto é feito através de testes automatizados com Web Driver e diferentes instâncias com os browsers suportados. Obviamente não tem cada versão e às vezes ocorrem regressões. É impossível verificar tudo.

Em cima disso, uma técnica legal que implementaram para evitar regressões em elementos visuais (que geralmente passam batidos) foi utilizar capturas de tela durante os testes e comparar com as versões anteriores.

Adicionalmente é importante que os desenvolvedores saibam o que estão usando, principalmente no que se refere a HTML, JavaScript e CSS. Isso inclui analisar a compatibilidade de todas as bibliotecas, componentes e frameworks utilizados, além das funcionalidades utilizadas. Nesse caso, referências como [*Can I use*](http://caniuse.com/) e [Mozilla Web references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) são bastante úteis.

O lado do servidor não traz tanta preocupação nesse sentido, mas ainda envolve alguns cuidados. Browsers tem diferentes comportamentos em diferentes contextos. Por exemplo, dependendo dos cabeçalhos HTTP enviados pelo navegador os cookies não expirar conforme esperado, requisições JSON podem não funcionar bem, uploads de arquivo podem ter cabeçalhos diferentes, etc.

No fim das contas, suportar diversos navegadores em suas diferentes versões significa que você vai ter que abrir mão de alguns recursos mais avançados ou manter variadas versões desses recursos. Um exemplo é permitir múltiplos uploads com *drag & drop* em navegadores modernos enquanto você retrocede (*fallback*) para um campo simples em navegadores mais antigos.

Especificamente para o JavaScript, evite fazer `if`s para versões específicas de navegadores, a não ser em caso de querer contornar algum bug que também seja específico. Procure usar uma técnica de detecção de funcionalidades (*feature detection*). Uma forma de fazer isso sem adentrar nos detalhes específicos de cada item é usando uma biblioteca como [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/). Então ao invés de fazer algo como `if (ie > 11)` você vai ter, por exemplo, `if (suportaWebSockets)`.